Function taking different parameter types but with same logic
I've a method with below signature. here UserSettingType is an Enum
public async Task<T> Foo(string Id, IList<UserSettingType> inputSettingsTypes1, Func<IMyService, Task<T>> invokeBackEndFn)
{   
    T resultfromService1 = await invokeBackEndFn(service1);
    T resultfromService2 = await GetResultFromService2(invokeBackEndFn, Id, inputSettingsTypes1);
    T mergedResult = MergeResult(resultfromService1, resultfromService2, Id);
    return mergedResult;   
}

Now, I need to extend the same logic to another Enum type
public async Task<T> Foo(string Id, IList<TeamsSettingType> inputSettingsTypes2, Func<IMyService, Task<T>> invokeBackEndFn)
{
    T resultfromService1 = await invokeBackEndFn(service1);
    T resultfromService2 = await GetResultFromService2(invokeBackEndFn, Id, inputSettingsTypes2);
    T mergedResult = MergeResult(resultfromService1, resultfromService2, Id);
    return mergedResult;
}

TeamsSettingType is also an Enum without any inheritance hierarchy with UserSettingType.
Currently, I created Overloaded Foo Method to accept different param type and duplicated the logic & refactored logic not related to type to a common method so both Foo methods can reuse them.
public enum UserSettingType
{
   Meeting,
   Permission
   // few other values
}
public enum TeamsSettingType
{
   MeetingPolicy,
   PermissionPolicy
   // few other values
}

My logic relies on checking for a value in passed enum list and doing a backend call with the passed in InvokeBackendFn delegate.
for eg:
if(UserSettingType.Contains(UserSettingType.Permission))
    invokeBackendFn(MyService2);

if(UserSettingType.Contains(TeamsSettingType.PermissionPolicy))
    invokeBackendFn(MyService2);

As you see, I've to check for Permission in UserSettingType while I should check for PermissionPolicy in TeamsSettingType to execute the same backendcode.
However, this looks ugly, I want to understand if there is a better way to handle such scenarios with some design patterns in C#.

Think about why you are able to write exactly the same code for UserSettingType and TeamsSettingType. What is common between those two enums that your implementation of Foo relies on? Without knowing that this question cannot be answered. I'd suggest showing how you implement Foo, if you can.

sorry, Updated my Foo Implementation

Both, UserSettingType.Permission and TeamsSettingType.PermissionPolicy, are (T)1, assuming the T is one of these two enums.

that enum order can change, I just showed a concise version to show how the logic is using the enums

Then pass this function the value as parameter T settingType.

And then that T is List of Enum's right? How do we identify the corresponding type to check for Permission or PermissionPolicy enums? Isnt that code is also an if based condition to check for passed in Enum list type?

Must you use enum? In c#, an enum is basically a collection of compile-time constants. The values you get from an enum might be represented in other ways as well.

yeah, I am modifying an existing big codebase which is already using this Enum. if I have to change to list or somethign I have to touch many places which makes my PR unnecessarily huge and tough to get it reviewed and merged.
So I am tied there for Enum.

You can Use Something Like this:
public async Task<T> Foo<T, TSettingType>(string Id, IList<TSettingType> inputSettingsTypes1, Func<object, Task<T>> invokeBackEndFn) where TSettingType : struct, enum
{
    T resultfromService1 = await invokeBackEndFn(service1);
    T resultfromService2 = await GetResultFromService2(invokeBackEndFn, Id, inputSettingsTypes1);
    T mergedResult = MergeResult(resultfromService1, resultfromService2, Id);
    return mergedResult;
}

For more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#constraining-multiple-parameters

thanks Prabhat. And how would I check if the enum contains a value? foeg: if TSettingType is UserSettingType, I want to check for UserSettingType.Permission
else if enum is TeamsSettingType, I want to check for TeamsSettingType.PermissionPolicy
Is it really an If else condition? if there is a third enum type tomorrow, we need to extend the if else as well. right.

From the above question what I understood is that you need a way to refactor, and your from  the code I understood that you need to you are passing the enum into the function without currently checking it. The both method you provide uses GetResultFromService2, as per the requirement I provided a way to combine those two method.
That's why I wrote "you could use something like" and not exactly.
Please state clearly your requirement.
Thanks
